# How to define segue relationships for controller?

Tags: ios5, storyboard

For example with UISplitViewController under "Storyboard Segues" there is:

- Relationship - detailViewController
- Relationship - masterViewContoller

For my own UIViewController I would like to define segue relationships that I can map just like I can with a UISplitViewController.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Any luck working out how to do this? A am trying to accomplish exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, but you probably want use UINavigationController and then you'll be able to map segue relationships.

You should think of UISplitViewController as kind of UINavigationController.

Please note a that UISplitViewController and UINavigationController both share a NSArray *viewControllers property.

Hope this help